# Continuous updating image - django

Tags: html, django, asynchronous

What I am looking to achieve is to have a page hosted by django. One part of this page will be an svg image which I retrieve as a parameter from within one of my programs objects.

Basically what I want is to be able to update the svg image without having to refresh the page. Im also going to have a second html element that I want to update in a similar method.

Edit: to clarify I am looking at having the updates be triggered by the server as opposed to client side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your page a piece of javascript.
In this way you will be able to call your django project through an ajax call and (then) update the image without reloading the entire page.

If you have no experience, give a try to jQuery (https://jquery.com/), it can help you on the javascript side.
It's pretty simple to make an ajax call.

On the django side, you need to implement a view that return a json structure with all the information you need to update the image.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I have seen Ajax, however my understanding is that Ajax is driven on the client side. I'm after server side triggering so to speak. Sorry I hadn't put this in the question at the start my apologies.

Comment: you have a couple of solutions in this case:
1. if the server refresh the image with a low rate, you can enable a js timer and trigger the ajax call on a regular basis (ie. every second)
2. if the server refresh the image very fast, you can give a try to websockets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)